# System.UnauthorizedAccessException in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I was developing an ASP.NET application. Then I did not test the application in the debugger of Visual Studio, but transferred it via File Deploy to another server. The application works there.

After I shut down the computer, I wanted to develop again. Since then, I can no longer launch my application in the Visual Studio debugger / IIS. The following error message always appears:

> Exception raised: "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" in mscorlib.dll ("The access to the path" C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework \ v4.0.30319 \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ AspCheck_b8e5127411412.tmp "was denied." )

The mentioned path does not contain any file.

Why are there no more assemblies any more? Is this a special setting that was made when I was publishing to another destination?

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: I get the feeling the folder called **Temporary ASP.NET Files** was either deleted or not replicated, on acount of it being a Temporary folder.

Comment: @Christopher But why? And how do I get the files back? I am totally sure that I did not delete them manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Temporary ASP.NET Files** it is where .NET dynamically store your compiled site. For example every *.cs file in **App_Code** folder will be built into a *i23y4ui*.dll and moved to a *247ksdfklj* folder. Those names are formed dynamically as well.

What I would recommend is that

**Option #1:**

On your DEV machine you

- go to this folder:

  > C: \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
- Stop IIS or IIS Express
- and delete everything inside the folder.
  This will force your application to recompile entirely.

**Option #2**:

Is to start your Visual Studio as administrator. Sometimes of the windows options are kind of locked for some users and this may also cause this error. This happens more often when the site is hosted in IIS.

**Option #3:**

Create a folder with FULL access to "EVERYONE" and set it in your compile element in the web.config

```
<system.web>
            <compilation tempDirectory="C:\MyCompilationTest\temporary_asp_net_files\test1" />
        </system.web>
```

Comment: Option #1: The folder is already empty. I think this is the problem. I am using the IIS of Visual Studio. This should be restarted everytime I start debugging?
Option #2: Does not work for me either.

Comment: @DanielSchneider I am running out of options :D, I hope option #3 can help you.

Comment: Noteworthy is that the path may also be:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files depending on your version of windows.

Answer (score 2):

If it still can help anyone, it just happened to me.

Solution:
From the project directory, deleting the .suo file in folder `.vs/config/[projectName]/v16` (for Visual Studio 2019) and restarting Visual Studio made the error disappear.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For others facing similar issue, do note this can also be caused by a bug in your own code. In my case, I had the wrong model assigned to the view in the MVC controller.

```
In controller:
MyWrongModel model = new MyWrongModel();
return View(model);

In View:
@model CorrectModel;
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jack said, you can have this issue when you have a bug in your code - even if build is successful.  I ran into this with a duplicate rewrite rule name, so if you've modified your .config file[s] check there!

Answer (score 1):

I had this stupid problem twice and it's always for installing Microsoft Visual x86 elements, or having duplicate installs of the same year's edition.
Removing them seems to do the trick at the two times...

Answer (score 0):

Another simple coding error, with a very strange run-time exception thrown.

In my case:

```
string ourRegexToMatch = "\b(Drop|Delete|Insert\b";
```

I forgot the closing parenthesis, and this caused a problem.

Probably there should be a better error message for this situation.